# Is unvoiced & unaspirated a category of speech?

Tags: phonology, voicing, aspiration

I know there is 'voiced & unaspirated' and 'aspirated & unvoiced' categories of speech. I have heard there is a 3rd category. What is it?

Answer (score 2):

Aspiration and voicing are not mutually exclusive phenomenon. You can certainly have a plosive that is voiceless (the more usual term for what you give as "unvoiced") and unaspirated (the one you are missing above), like [p] in English *spin* [spɪn], one that is voiceless and aspirated, like [pʰ] in English *pin* [pʰɪn], one that is voiced and unaspirated, like [b] in English *bin* [bɪn], and you can even have voiced and aspirated consonants, like [bʰ].

This last category is debated. [Ladefoged (1971: 9)](http://books.google.com/books?id=VqEXghQ-ow0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false) claims that such a sound "has yet to be observed", while [Blust (2006)](https://muse.jhu.edu/login?auth=0&type=summary&url=/journals/oceanic_linguistics/v045/45.2blust.pdf) has shown that Kelabit, an Austronesian language, contrasts a series of voiceless unaspirated stops, voiced unaspirated stops, and voiced aspirated stops. For instance:

- /tutuʔ/ 'fall from a height'
- /tuduʔ/ 'seven'
- /tudʰuʔ/ 'salt' (all from Blust 2006: 314)

Comment: `Voiced` and `Aspirated` are independent phonetic categories. They can describe consonants or vowels (though most vowels are voiced and unaspirated, all combinations do occur), and they both refer to co-articulation of the larynx and pharynx with the mouth. English speakers can observe aspiration in the puff of air that accompanies the /p/ in _pin_, but is absent from the /p/ in _spin_; every voiceless stop in English is aspirated when it begins a stressed syllable. Voicing is even simpler: /b/ versus /p/. Hold both stops as long as you can, and observe differences. /b/ is the voiced one.

Answer (score 0):

Vedic Sanskrit, Classical Sanskrit and accordingly a lot of middle Indian and new Indian languages have for each of five positions of plosive-articulation all combinations of voiced/non-voiced and aspirated/non-aspirated stops. The alphabet is structured accordingly, for each of the positions (from back to front: velar, palatal, retroflex, dental, labial) there are five sounds (examples from the labial *varga*):

1. non-aspirated voiceless: [p]
2. aspirated voiceless: [pʰ]
3. non-aspirated voiced: [b]
4. aspirated voiced: [bʰ]
5. nasal: [m]

Regarding this, I don't really get Ladefoged's claim cited in @limetom's answer.

Comment: Whether or not those languages have "aspirated voiced" stops is a terminological issue. From a phonetic perspective, the stops in question are not truly aspirated, but rather "murmured".  Accordingly, they are transcribed as [bʱ], [dʱ], etc. instead of [bʰ], [dʰ], etc. See the intro paragraphs of [the Wikipedia article on Breathy Voice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmured).

Comment: I agree that the question of whether these phonemes are "aspirated","breathy" or "murmured" is a terminological issue about which there is no consensus among phoneticians.